# Send multicast from eth0 to eth1

Tags: c, linux, multicast

I need to send multicast data from eth0 interface and receive it on eth1 on Linux machine.
I have 2 programs in C, PROG-1 does setsockopt IP_MULTICAST_IF so that it would send from eth0, PROG-2 does join mcast group on eth1 ( verified with netstat -ng) but can't see any multicast traffic on eth1. I can only see multicast data on eth0. I increased TTL but no help. Is there any way to receive multicast sent from eth0 on eth1?
IP_MULTICAST_LOOP does not help either, it works only when both programs working on the same interface, and this is no good for me.
It's a custom protocol over ipv4.

Sender code:

```
sock_fd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 100 );
srcip = inet_addr("10.1.231.112"); /* src mcast from eth0 */
ret_val = setsockopt( sock_fd,
                      IPPROTO_IP,
                      IP_MULTICAST_IF,
                      &srcip,
                      sizeof( srcip ));    
ttl = 0x2;
ret_val = setsockopt( sock_fd,
                      IPPROTO_IP,
                      IP_MULTICAST_TTL,
                      ( char * ) &ttl,
                      sizeof( ttl ));

dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.100.1.102");
dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest_addr.sin_port = 0;

ret_val = sendto(sock_fd, (char *) buf,
            (size_t) 64, 0, /* no flags */
            (struct sockaddr *) &dest_addr, addr_len);
```

Receiver code:

```
sock_fd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 100 );
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.100.1.102");
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.3.15"); /* join on eth1 */
ret_val = setsockopt( sock_fd,
                      IPPROTO_IP,
                      IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
                      ( char * ) &mreq,
                      sizeof( mreq ));
msglen = recvfrom(sock_fd, buf, 4096, 0,
        (struct sockaddr*)&addr_struct, &addr_len);
```

I verified with netstat -ng that receiver is joined the group on the eth1, but the message sent by the sender is only visible on eth0 (wireshark on eth1 does not capture anything).

Let me explain exact problem I'm facing. I have a production code which normally runs on proprietary hardware. This is a piece of software for network communication. All communication is done via multicast. The architecture is that there is a TX task which is sending multicast data to other devices in the network, unfortunately there is a RX task also which is joining the same group as TX task sends data to, because other network devices are communicating with my device on the same mcast address. On production code we have multicast loop disabled and everything is ok, RX task does not receive what TX task is sending. Now we decided to run this software on a linux machine for testing purposes, on the same machine we want to run a software which is simulating all other boxes. What I wanted to accomplish it to "bind" all mcast sockets on production code to eth0 and on simulator on eth1. But I can't have them communicate with each other. I can configure my network interfaces as I need, add vlans, interfaces or anything, just to make it communicate one with another. What I can't do is to change the architecture of this software.

Comment: what protocol is used here (ipv4 or v6) ? what multicast address is specified? why don't you post your code?

Comment: Are your 2 NICs on different IP subnets or VLANs ? If so your router usually need a few special configuration knobs to pass the traffic between them.

Comment: How about using a reflector, a helper process that acts as a bridge between the two multicast addresses? Your reflector might have to keep track of messages it has already forwarded (so that each message crosses the reflector "bridge" only once), but other than that, it should be quite a simple program, especially if you have something in the messages itself, in the protocol, that makes uniquely identifying messages simple.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at igmpproxy http://sourceforge.net/projects/igmpproxy/
It receives multicast packets on one interface and then broadcasts it to specified others.